# Retrofit responce body recieved half object with null fields

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to get list of objects using Retrofit, but response body is half empty and list contains null fields. Server is sending proper response, but I'm still not getting these values in application. How to solve it?

Part of my REST service class:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

 @GET("listings/{listingId}/images")
    Call<ListingImages> getImages(@Path("listingId") String listingId,
                                  @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

REST server response

```
{
  "count": 5,
  "results": [
    {
      "listing_image_id": 207779028,
      "hex_code": "D9CEBF",
      "red": 217,
      "green": 206,
      "blue": 191,
      "hue": 34,
      "saturation": 11,
      "brightness": 85,
      "is_black_and_white": false,
      "creation_tsz": 1299877281,
      "listing_id": 65811540,
      "rank": 1,
      "url_75x75": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_75x75.207779028.jpg",
      "url_170x135": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_170x135.207779028.jpg",
      "url_570xN": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_570xN.207779028.jpg",
      "url_fullxfull": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_fullxfull.207779028.jpg",
      "full_height": 1500,
      "full_width": 1125
    },
    {
      "listing_image_id": 207778696,
      "hex_code": "BFC0AA",
      "red": 191,
      "green": 192,
      "blue": 170,
      "hue": 62,
      "saturation": 11,
      "brightness": 75,
      "is_black_and_white": false,
      "creation_tsz": 1299877281,
      "listing_id": 65811540,
      "rank": 2,
      "url_75x75": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_75x75.207778696.jpg",
      "url_170x135": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_170x135.207778696.jpg",
      "url_570xN": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_570xN.207778696.jpg",
      "url_fullxfull": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_fullxfull.207778696.jpg",
      "full_height": 1125,
      "full_width": 1500
    },
    {
      "listing_image_id": 207778607,
      "hex_code": "BBBBA6",
      "red": 187,
      "green": 187,
      "blue": 166,
      "hue": 60,
      "saturation": 11,
      "brightness": 73,
      "is_black_and_white": false,
      "creation_tsz": 1299877281,
      "listing_id": 65811540,
      "rank": 3,
      "url_75x75": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_75x75.207778607.jpg",
      "url_170x135": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_170x135.207778607.jpg",
      "url_570xN": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_570xN.207778607.jpg",
      "url_fullxfull": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_fullxfull.207778607.jpg",
      "full_height": 1125,
      "full_width": 1500
    },
    {
      "listing_image_id": 207778809,
      "hex_code": "BDBCA9",
      "red": 189,
      "green": 188,
      "blue": 169,
      "hue": 57,
      "saturation": 10,
      "brightness": 74,
      "is_black_and_white": false,
      "creation_tsz": 1299877281,
      "listing_id": 65811540,
      "rank": 4,
      "url_75x75": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_75x75.207778809.jpg",
      "url_170x135": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_170x135.207778809.jpg",
      "url_570xN": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_570xN.207778809.jpg",
      "url_fullxfull": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_fullxfull.207778809.jpg",
      "full_height": 1500,
      "full_width": 1125
    },
    {
      "listing_image_id": 207778913,
      "hex_code": "E2D7C6",
      "red": 226,
      "green": 215,
      "blue": 198,
      "hue": 36,
      "saturation": 12,
      "brightness": 88,
      "is_black_and_white": false,
      "creation_tsz": 1299877281,
      "listing_id": 65811540,
      "rank": 5,
      "url_75x75": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_75x75.207778913.jpg",
      "url_170x135": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_170x135.207778913.jpg",
      "url_570xN": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_570xN.207778913.jpg",
      "url_fullxfull": "https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5499432/il_fullxfull.207778913.jpg",
      "full_height": 1500,
      "full_width": 1125
    }
  ],
  "params": {
    "listing_id": "65811540"
  },
  "type": "ListingImage",
  "pagination": {}
}
```

Class where I try to get REST query:

```
public class GetImages {
    EtsyService etsyService;
    final private String API_KEY = "00000000000000000000";//fake key

    public List<ListingEntity> fillModel(List<ListingEntity> listingList){

        etsyService = EtsyService.retrofit.create(EtsyService.class);

        for(final ListingEntity listingentity:listingList){

            final Call<ListingImages> call = etsyService.getImages(listingentity.getListing_id(),API_KEY);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ListingImages>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ListingImages> call, Response<ListingImages> response) {
                    listingentity.setListingImagesUrl(response.body().getResults());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ListingImages> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(),call.toString());
                }
            });
        }
        return listingList;
    }
}
```

I receive the response from the server, but not of all fields are filled.

[image: Response body in debugger]

Model of response (generated using gson2pojo service)

```
public class ListingImages {

    private Integer count;
    private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    private Params params;
    private String type;
    private Pagination pagination;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public ListingImages() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param results
     * @param count
     * @param params
     * @param pagination
     * @param type
     */
    public ListingImages(Integer count, List<Result> results, Params params, String type, Pagination pagination) {
        this.count = count;
        this.results = results;
        this.params = params;
        this.type = type;
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The count
     */
    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param count
     *     The count
     */
    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The results
     */
    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param results
     *     The results
     */
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The params
     */
    public Params getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param params
     *     The params
     */
    public void setParams(Params params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param type
     *     The type
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The pagination
     */
    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return pagination;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param pagination
     *     The pagination
     */
    public void setPagination(Pagination pagination) {
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Class of results from previous class (generated on gson2pojo service)

```
public class Result {

    private Integer listingImageId;
    private String hexCode;
    private String red;
    private int green;
    private Integer blue;
    private Integer hue;
    private Integer saturation;
    private Integer brightness;
    private Boolean isBlackAndWhite;
    private Integer creationTsz;
    private Integer listingId;
    private Integer rank;
    private String url75x75;
    private String url170x135;
    private String url570xN;
    private String urlFullxfull;
    private Integer fullHeight;
    private Integer fullWidth;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Result() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url570xN
     * @param urlFullxfull
     * @param url170x135
     * @param green
     * @param hue
     * @param fullWidth
     * @param fullHeight
     * @param listingId
     * @param isBlackAndWhite
     * @param brightness
     * @param rank
     * @param red
     * @param blue
     * @param saturation
     * @param creationTsz
     * @param hexCode
     * @param url75x75
     * @param listingImageId
     */
    public Result(Integer listingImageId, String hexCode, String red, int green, Integer blue, Integer hue, Integer saturation, Integer brightness, Boolean isBlackAndWhite, Integer creationTsz, Integer listingId, Integer rank, String url75x75, String url170x135, String url570xN, String urlFullxfull, Integer fullHeight, Integer fullWidth) {
        this.listingImageId = listingImageId;
        this.hexCode = hexCode;
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        this.hue = hue;
        this.saturation = saturation;
        this.brightness = brightness;
        this.isBlackAndWhite = isBlackAndWhite;
        this.creationTsz = creationTsz;
        this.listingId = listingId;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.url75x75 = url75x75;
        this.url170x135 = url170x135;
        this.url570xN = url570xN;
        this.urlFullxfull = urlFullxfull;
        this.fullHeight = fullHeight;
        this.fullWidth = fullWidth;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The listingImageId
     */
    public Integer getListingImageId() {
        return listingImageId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param listingImageId
     *     The listing_image_id
     */
    public void setListingImageId(Integer listingImageId) {
        this.listingImageId = listingImageId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The hexCode
     */
    public String getHexCode() {
        return hexCode;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param hexCode
     *     The hex_code
     */
    public void setHexCode(String hexCode) {
        this.hexCode = hexCode;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The red
     */
    public String getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param red
     *     The red
     */
    public void setRed(String red) {
        this.red = red;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The green
     */
    public int getGreen() {
        return green;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param green
     *     The green
     */
    public void setGreen(int green) {
        this.green = green;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The blue
     */
    public Integer getBlue() {
        return blue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param blue
     *     The blue
     */
    public void setBlue(Integer blue) {
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The hue
     */
    public Integer getHue() {
        return hue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param hue
     *     The hue
     */
    public void setHue(Integer hue) {
        this.hue = hue;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The saturation
     */
    public Integer getSaturation() {
        return saturation;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param saturation
     *     The saturation
     */
    public void setSaturation(Integer saturation) {
        this.saturation = saturation;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The brightness
     */
    public Integer getBrightness() {
        return brightness;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param brightness
     *     The brightness
     */
    public void setBrightness(Integer brightness) {
        this.brightness = brightness;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The isBlackAndWhite
     */
    public Boolean getIsBlackAndWhite() {
        return isBlackAndWhite;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param isBlackAndWhite
     *     The is_black_and_white
     */
    public void setIsBlackAndWhite(Boolean isBlackAndWhite) {
        this.isBlackAndWhite = isBlackAndWhite;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The creationTsz
     */
    public Integer getCreationTsz() {
        return creationTsz;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param creationTsz
     *     The creation_tsz
     */
    public void setCreationTsz(Integer creationTsz) {
        this.creationTsz = creationTsz;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The listingId
     */
    public Integer getListingId() {
        return listingId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param listingId
     *     The listing_id
     */
    public void setListingId(Integer listingId) {
        this.listingId = listingId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The rank
     */
    public Integer getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param rank
     *     The rank
     */
    public void setRank(Integer rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The url75x75
     */
    public String getUrl75x75() {
        return url75x75;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url75x75
     *     The url_75x75
     */
    public void setUrl75x75(String url75x75) {
        this.url75x75 = url75x75;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The url170x135
     */
    public String getUrl170x135() {
        return url170x135;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url170x135
     *     The url_170x135
     */
    public void setUrl170x135(String url170x135) {
        this.url170x135 = url170x135;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The url570xN
     */
    public String getUrl570xN() {
        return url570xN;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url570xN
     *     The url_570xN
     */
    public void setUrl570xN(String url570xN) {
        this.url570xN = url570xN;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The urlFullxfull
     */
    public String getUrlFullxfull() {
        return urlFullxfull;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param urlFullxfull
     *     The url_fullxfull
     */
    public void setUrlFullxfull(String urlFullxfull) {
        this.urlFullxfull = urlFullxfull;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The fullHeight
     */
    public Integer getFullHeight() {
        return fullHeight;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param fullHeight
     *     The full_height
     */
    public void setFullHeight(Integer fullHeight) {
        this.fullHeight = fullHeight;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The fullWidth
     */
    public Integer getFullWidth() {
        return fullWidth;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param fullWidth
     *     The full_width
     */
    public void setFullWidth(Integer fullWidth) {
        this.fullWidth = fullWidth;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

`Param` and `Pagination` classed are included in the project too.

Comment: Check your Json in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Checked. and i tried two different service of pojo generating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is generated by the `GsonConverterFactory`, if you don't annotate the fields of your classes that will be parsed, the field name should match exactly with the key in JSON.

For example `creation_tsz` in JSON, you have to have the same name in the class in order to automatically parse it.

You have two options, annotate the fields from classes with `@Serisalized` annotation, or find a way to set the field name policy of  `GsonConverterFactory` to one of the values from [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html). Use the best policy for you.

Just a side note, I always annotate the fields, just to be sure it's because I annotated something stupid and it's not a bug from the library.

**EDIT 1**

I found how you can change the field name policy with retrofit:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES).create()
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
.build();
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working with annotation @SerializedName
  
  For example for field url_fullxfull
@SerializedName("url_fullxfull")
    private String urlFullxfull;

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it ass accepted answer :) (only if you want, off-course)

Comment: I want but i can't ) I voted but it will mark only when i receive 15 points of reputation